# Is there a way to give debugging rights for a particular database in SQLServer?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

In SQLServer 2008, there are multiple databases available. I have **db_owner** rights for a particular xyz database, but the Sys Admin is not able to give me **sysadmin** rights, which are required to debug a stored procedure stored in the  database.

Can anyone guide me regarding how to **debug a stored procedure** written in the xyz database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PRINT function after critical lines to write out result of specific set and that's one way of debugging, though little deprecated.

Other way is to try to give to login a specific permissions needed for DEBUG stored procedures, like VIEW SERVER STATE, VIEW DATABASE STATE, maybe even ALTER TRACE.